# contract/contractor/contracting

Tags: grammar

I'm soliciting a position as a contractor (avoiding the status of a permanent employee).  Which is correct (or better than any of these)?

- I am looking employment in a contract capacity
- I am looking employment in a contracting capacity
- I am looking employment in a contractor's capacity
- I am looking employment in a contractor capacity

I vote for contract, but I'm not sure.

Comment: In the UK it would probably be wise not to make a big deal of the idea that you want to be a contractor rather than a permanent employee. If the company specifically wants you to be one or the other they'll set the terms anyway. But they can get involved in *very* expensive disputes with the Inland Revenue if they pay you as a contractor when you're actually working as a "de facto" permanent employee. If I were doing the hiring, I'd be wary of taking on someone who might be predisposed to mislead me, and cause me to fall foul of the taxman.

Comment: On that basis, please bear in mind that ELU.SE **does not offer employment advice.** We only advise on the Use of English -- and even taking *that* advice is up to you.

Comment: Also note: It's either "I'm looking ***for*** employment" or "I'm seeking employment"

Comment: Don't write fancy letters in languages you don't speak. Let them be surprised at how well you speak, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Of those, I would say "contracting" because it's now an adjective modifying "capacity".

But why not just "as a contractor"?

Comment: I will use that.  It is so much better.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have just gone through the switch from permanent to contract myself (and have signed my first contract in the last week). The terms I was using in my frequent discussions with recruitment agents were:

- I am looking for a contract rather than permanent employment
- I am moving from permanent to contracting and I am seeking my first contract
- I am a contractor
- I am looking for contract work, I am not interested in permanent work/employment

In my opinion you are not "... looking for a position as a contractor", you **are** a contractor looking for a contract position (i.e. **not** a permanent employee looking for a contract or a permanent employee looking for a permanent position)

Comment: +1, especially for the opinion stated in your last paragraph. OP could take that advice, get a little fancy, and amend your third bullet to: "I am a contractor (and I'm) looking for a position as such."